# Spring boot - number of backup log files restricted to 7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

In our **spring-boot** project we are using **slf4j** for logging purpose. Below are configuration which we have added in **application.properties** file

```
logging.file=/opt/logs/my_log.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
logging.level.nl.yestelecom.boss=DEBUG
logging.level.com.github.isrsal.logging.LoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

It **generates only 7 backup files** (my_log.log.1, my_log.log.2 ..., my_log.log.7) with each file of size **10.5MB** and after that logging is not happening at all.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

We looked into available properties of spring-boot but, didn't find anything. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Spring-Boot** only allows limited properties to be configured in its application.properties. See the [list here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

The default (out-of-the-box) configuration that Spring-boot uses is defined in base.xml. See [base.xml config here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b6fd1b515d887009da978e02b62b8d2426adfb2b/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml) which includes [this File appender](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml)

There are 2 ways to add extra configuration

1. **Add logback-spring.xml**

If there is a logback configuration XML with name logback-spring.xml in project's classpath, it is picked up by Spring-Boot on initialization.

2. **Point to config file from application.properties**

Within application.properties use following to point to your custom logback XML

```
logging.config= # Location of the logging configuration file. For instance `classpath:logback.xml` for Logback
```

Once you add the extra config using any of the above 2 steps, the rollover strategy can be mentioned within that custom XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak for the detailed answer :)

Comment: Spring boot seems to ignore certain properies, so this answer is the most reliable IME. I was trying to change the max file size for example and couldn't get it to work. So if you override to point to your own logback xml file and put everything in there, it definitely works.

Answer (score 8):

SFL4J is just wrapper. You need to add extra configuration for logback library:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>

    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

[source](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)

In this case we have logs from last 30 days but not bigger than 3GB.

Comment: Thanks @Koziolek for the immediate reply. I was thinking how to load this file and I got Deepak's answer :)

Answer (score 4):

for spring-boot 2.0.0:

- logging.file.max-history
- logging.file.max-size

...and others
Either look at `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemProperties` or
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output

Comment: What do you observe?  All those settings depend on you not having a specialized logback.xml, that'd override the org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml.  Maybe if you use  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" /> in your <configuration> it works?

Comment: I haven't created any xml file. I have set these properties in `application.properties`. `Max-size` does work but `max-history` is totally ignored.

Comment: What do you see, when you look at spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!\org\springframework\boot\logging\logback\file-appender.xml?  There should be <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-0}</maxHistory> in there...

Comment: Yes `<maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-0}</maxHistory>` is present in `file-appender.xml`.

Comment: It seems to me there's a bug in `logback`. I tried `log4j2` using this tutorial and worked! https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-log4j2-config/

Comment: I just updated my working logback config, and I remember faintly, that this here was important for everything to work with logback:
      <totalSizeCap>50mb</totalSizeCap>
...or any other totalSizeCap.