# How to set max number of archived logs in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I tried following settings in `application.properties`:

```
logging.file=foo/bar.log
logging.file.max-history=2
logging.file.max-size=1KB
```

Still, its not limiting the number of archive logs to 2.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to solve this?

Comment: @Arya yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610495/spring-boot-number-of-backup-log-files-restricted-to-7/49025056#comment91923497_49025056

Answer (score 1):

As per application properties documentation reference, only supported when you setup `logback`.

```
logging.file.max-history=0 # Maximum of archive log files to keep. Only supported with the default logback setup.
```

So to add support of logback please see section `79.1 Configure Logback for Logging` & `79.1.1 Configure Logback for File-only Output` of [Spring Boot Logging Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)

> If you want to disable console logging and write output only to a
>   file, you need a custom logback-spring.xml that imports
>   file-appender.xml but not console-appender.xml, as shown in the
>   following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I created a file `logback-spring.xml`. Here are its contents: https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/74c3ec3cfb38711e3309437379f3b950

It correctly output the logs only to the File but it isn't limiting the number of archived logs.